# Ratio of lengths of two confidence intervalls

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, asymptotics, t-distribution

I have two random variables:

(1) With standard normal distribution. Confidence interval $I_1$, which is centered and has probability of $(1-\alpha)$

(2) With T-distribution. Confidence intervall intervall $I_2$, also centered and has prob. $(1-\alpha)$.

First I had to compute the length of both:
I got $\mathcal{L}(I_1) = 2 \cdot z_{1-\alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $\mathcal{L}(I_2) = 2 \cdot t_{1-\alpha/2;n-1} \frac{S}{\sqrt{n}}$. Hope this is correct.

Now I have to calculate the asymptotic distribution of the ratio: $\Lambda = \frac{\mathcal{L}(I_2)^2}{\mathcal{L}(I_1)^2}$. As a hint I got $(n-1)\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi_{n-1}^2$.

So far I got: $\Lambda = \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{t_{1-\alpha/2;n-1}^2}\cdot\frac{S^2}{\sigma^2}$.

How do I express the ratio of the two distributions? I know that t-Distribution gets to a standard normal if n goes to infinity, but does that help? And do I get the $(n-1)$ from the hint somehow, or is this not really relevant?

Comment: At a fixed $\alpha$, the ratio is a constant. The critical values themselves come from the inverse of the cdf (the quantile function).

Comment: Glen, thanks for the hint! That the ratio of the CDFs will be a constant is clear to me. But after some googling I still do not know how to proceed. Do I first calculate the second power of the two distributions and then calculate the ratio or vice versa? How do I get more info regarding the way that works? Thanks!!!

Comment: It's not a ratio of cdfs (cdfs are between 0 and 1, for starters), but a ratio of the inverse-cdfs (quantile function). You specify $\alpha$ (and the df for the $t$) and you can compute those quantiles and then take their ratio.

Comment: Sorry, sure we have iCDF... But I am still not sure about the solution. So $t_{1-\alpha/2}^2$ gets normal for n to infinity, right? So the term with the two distributions gets cancelled to 1? And then we can use the hint with Chi square. But because chi square for infinite n is normal, we end up with a standard normal distribution for the ratio of the two confidence intervals?

Comment: If you think of $\frac{z^2}{t^2(n-1)}$ as a constant, $g$ (it varies with $n$ and $\alpha$, which are constants), then $\Lambda \sim g\chi^2_{n-1}$. Asymptotically, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{z^2}{t^2} = 1$. So $g\chi^2_{n-1}\to ...$ -- it's possible to carry the analysis further, but I don't know whether the intent if for you to do further approximation.